# How to get Identity value whith help of scope_identity()

Tags: sql, triggers, scope-identity

I have scope_identity() that implemented in TRIGGER.

```
ALTER TRIGGER TempProcTrig
ON Table_temp2
AFTER insert
AS
BEGIN

     declare @TempIdentity int
     set @TempIdentity =scope_identity() 
     insert Table_Temp(TempID) 
     values(@TempIdentity)
END
```

When TRIGGER is fired @TempIdentity gets Identity column field, 
and set this value into another table.

But, always after TRIGGER is fired, @TempIdentity gets NULL.

Why TempIdentity dosen't get Identity field? What should I change in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this issue is that, as the name implies, [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` only returns the id value from the **scope** that you call it in.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

Calling it from a trigger will return the identity value from within the **trigger**, which is `NULL` since you aren't inserting any rows.

As Joe suggests, use the `inserted` table to get the values needed instead of this function.

Answer (score 3):

First problem: You're writing your trigger with the assumption that only one row will be inserted. What happens if multiple rows are inserted by a single statement?

There is a special `inserted` table available in triggers that contains all of the rows inserted by the operation that caused the trigger to fire. You could use it this way:

```
INSERT INTO Table_Temp
    (TempID)
    SELECT i.YourIdentityColumn
        FROM inserted i
```

Comment: +1 - This is a super common issue (especially on SO in the past month or so)